# How do I count substrings within array of strings?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, count

I have an array:

`["Passive: 8", "Passive: 9", "Neutral: 3"]`

Now I need to count the number of times `Passive` is seen. How can I count the number of occurrences a substring is seen within strings inside of an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
["Passive: 8", "Passive: 9", "Neutral: 3"].grep(/Passive/).count
# => 2
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. This is also cleaner as it's one line of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer within `grep`.

```
arr.grep(/^Passive/).each do |element|
  ...
end
```

This will suffice for my purpose.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question you asked, it only finds the ones matching, and doesn't count them.

Comment: Agreed - This isn't complete, but I could iterate over each `element` and add one each time. However, sawa's answer is much more efficient.

Comment: @sawa's answer is also idiomatic Ruby. That it's a single line of code isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
array.count{|x|x['Passive']}
```